# Why does chromium inputs 'j' and 'k' characters when I scroll horizontally?

Tags: chromium, scrolling

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 on a Thinkpad T470s (don't think this is relevant) and when I'm scrolling horizontally in Chromium (version 63) and the cursor is in an input box it types `j` and `k` characters (`j` for left and `k` for right).

Some additional information:

- It works in the address bar and settings window so it can't be any extensions
- I'm using wayland on Gnome
- The behavior is exactly the same with touchpad and mouse
- In the stackoverflow editor box (which I'm typing this very question in) scrolling left does the usual `j` typing thing but scrolling right inputs a code block which suppose to have the shortcut `ctrl+k`.

If you want to "experiment" with it and have some edge case ideas let me know and I'll try them.

Comment: `j` and `k` can be used for scrolling, but what you describe doesn't look like intended behavior - you might try filling a bug report with Chromium project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that anyone else would ever run into this problem but for completeness sake I want to leave my solution here:

I'm using a mouse that has side-scroll wheels and I wanted to configure some custom shortcuts to that wheel. The only option I could found is to remap `Button 6` and `Button 7` with xbindkeys however it didn't work because I'm using wayland and not xorg. But after I set it and saw that it's not working I accidentally left the config in place. For some strange reason xbindkeys still somewhat works under wayland so my shortcuts (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) got executed partially (without <kbd>ctrl</kbd>).

Comment: Wow, that's crazy. Thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Ye Olde Days, `h` `j` `k` and `l` were the directional navigation keys for [left, down, up, and right, respectively](https://www.labnol.org/internet/j-k-keyboard-shortcuts/20779/).

Since `j` an `k` are [traditional shortcuts for down and up in Google products](http://smarterware.org/2009/08/google-tip-navigate-items-with-j-and-k-in-reader-gmail-and-search/), it seems like something is in a weird mode where it wants to send the shortcut keys in lieu of taking an action.

My vote is "bug."